# enable billing on google cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I don't know if is the correct place, but I can't enable the billing for a project on app engine to use a cloud storage, is there somebody with the same problem?

all look like work with the bonus but :
Billing Account Name    Billing Account ID  Status  # of Projects
My Billing Account ---- Closed  0
My Billing Dogtranslate ---- Closed 0
 and when I want  create a bucket it show me Error
You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page

I have tryed with another account and other credit card and it give me the same (It stolen me 0,90 euros each time) and dosn't work,

Maybe it needs some task that I don't know
(I have already contact the assistance in the past without result, just some useless email )

Answer (score 2):

I had a colleague that just had a similar problem. He was trying to activate billing for an App Engine instance using a credit card issued by Paypal. Google said they needed him to switch it to a regular credit card.

He had to delete the project that was blocked for billing, but was able to create a new project -- using the regular credit card -- with no problems.

Here's a link to their payment method info: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/2987880?hl=en&ref_topic=2991963

I think they were treating the Paypal card as a "prepaid card"

Comment: Thanks a lot all my credit card are "prepaid card", I'll try with different method

Comment: I have solved it with another account with normal credit account and another project because my older project was like disable. thanks a lot

Comment: Great. If that answer worked for you, please mark it as the correct answer to your problem. Good luck!